# What is wrong with my JSON output for a Slack Message payload?

Tags: javascript, json, slack, slack-api

I have set up what I think should be a working JSON output to send a message in slack but Slack keeps rejecting it.

I have tried multiple different message layout formats using the guides on slack's api site, but so far the only method that has successfully sent is a fully flat JSON with no block formatting.

```
function submitValuesToSlack(e) {

  var name = e.values[1];
  var caseNumber = e.values[2];
  var problemDescription = e.values[3];
  var question = e.values[4];
  var completedChecklist = e.values[5];

  var payload = [{
    "channel": postChannel,
    "username": postUser,
    "icon_emoji": postIcon,
    "link_names": 1,
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "section",
        "fields": [
          {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "*Name:*\n " + name
          }
        ]
      }]
  }];
  console.log(JSON.stringify(payload, null, "\t"));

  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  console.log(options)

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(slackIncomingWebhookUrl, options);

}
```

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
[  
   {  
      "channel":"#tech-support",
      "username":"Form Response",
      "icon_emoji":":mailbox_with_mail:",
      "link_names":1,
      "blocks":[  
         {  
            "type":"section",
            "fields":[  
               {  
                  "type":"mrkdwn",
                  "text":"*Name:*\n test"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Which I believe is correct, however slack api just rejects it with an HTTP 400 error "no text"

am I misunderstanding something about block formatting?

EDIT:

To Clarify, formatting works if I use this for my JSON instead of the more complex format:

```
{  
      "channel":"#tech-support",
      "username":"Form Response",
      "icon_emoji":":mailbox_with_mail:",
      "link_names":1,
      "text":"*Name:*\n test"
}
```

Comment: Is `payload` the correct property to assign data to in `options`? is this sent from  browser or server ?

Comment: I believe so, and slack does respond to this when I delete the additional formatting, aka if I just have:

```
{  
      "channel":"#tech-support",
      "username":"Form Response",
      "icon_emoji":":mailbox_with_mail:",
      "link_names":1,
      "text":"*Name:*\n test"
   }```

Comment: Looking over their API documentation I believe `"blocks":[]` is what's causing the problem. Try taking it out.

Comment: @EternalHour Sure, but that would not answer the question of OP

Comment: @ErikKalkoken It wasn't meant to be an answer, thus, it's a comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error `no_text` is because you do not have a valid message text property in your payload. You either need to have a text property as top line parameter (classic style - your example at the bottom) or a text block within a section block.

If you want to put to use blocks only (as you are asking) the section block is called `text`, not `fields`. `fields` is another type of section bock that has a different meaning.

So the correct syntax is:

```
[  
   {  
      "channel":"#tech-support",
      "username":"Form Response",
      "icon_emoji":":mailbox_with_mail:",
      "link_names":1,
      "blocks":[  
         {  
            "type":"section",
            "text":[  
               {  
                  "type":"mrkdwn",
                  "text":"*Name:*\n test"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Also see [here](https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/blocks#section) for the official documentation on it.

Blocks are very powerful, but can be complicated at times. I would recommend to use the message builder to try out your messages and check out the examples in the docu.

Comment: That was my issue yeah. The documentation is really confusing, agreed. Thanks for the response!